# Ошибки при постоянном соединении - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

После того, как устанавливаю параметр `p:` при коннекте к БД, в nginx error логах начинают вылетать ошибки. Как понял, данные ошибки возникают когда запрос пытается выполнится используя коннект который уже закрылся по тайму.

На сколько критичны подобные ошибки и влияют ли они на работу базы?

```
PHP message: PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: Ну если вам всё равно выполнится запрос или нет (а вы будете считать что выполнился), то не критично

Comment: Мы должны по ошибке, сфантазировать какой у вас код и написать его, я вас правильно понял да?

Comment: Попробуйте установить `mysqli.reconnect = On` в `php.ini` для автоматического переоткрытия закрытых соединений